# NavigationDrawer opening new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I implemented a basic `navigationDrawer`, with an array of strings. I want the user to click on something in the list and go to the corresponding `Activity`.
However, I am completely at loss here. I have read quite a few answers out here, but it still is not clear how to do this.

I have found a useful way for all the items combining the answers. However it is still returning my `MainActivity` instead of other activities.

The `addDrawerItems()` function:

```
public void addDrawerItems() {
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    String[] osArray = {"How-to", "Milestones", "Bridge & Beams", "Settings"};
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: //First item
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case 1: //Second item
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bridge_BeamsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
                case 2: //Third item
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MileStonesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;
                case 3: //Fourth item
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HowToActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now my `onCreate` where I call the `addDrawerItems()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Check if there is any saved data
    checkFirstRun();

    //Apply saved data
    savedData();

    //Apply drawer
    addDrawerItems();

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
If there are any unclear pieces of code or my explanation, please don't hesitate to reach out.

In case you want to see what is already there, please check out my beta app in the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jhpcoenen.connectlife.beams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code after setting the adapter:

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                pos =position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CorrespondingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


                switch (position) {
                    default:


                }

        }

});
```

The intent function will take to the desired activity.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After implementing the code, and AS suggesting to add `int` before `pos`, I ran the code. But when I clicked on any word in the `mDrawerList` it crashed

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to declare the new `Activity` in my `Manifest.xml`. It seems to work now, thank you a lot! Do I need to add anything to the new activity in order to get it to display everything? Now it is just a blank white screen.

Comment: I implemented `getIntent` with my new activity. But now it opens my mainActivity instead of SettingsActivity. `public class SettingsActivity extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    public Intent getIntent() {
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Bundle valueFromFirstActivity = intent.getExtras();
        String valueOfKey = intent.getStringExtra("key");
        return super.getIntent();
    }
}`

Comment: change the application context in the intent function if it requires.

Comment: How exactly? Because setting the context at `this`, does not seem to work.

Comment: write the name of your activity then write  ''your_activity.this" as context

Comment: I have combined the answer from you and other answers, but somehow it still returns my `MainActivity`. Any idea why? I've also updated the code to show what I am using now.

Comment: Maybe your app is getting confused with this implementation. If you pass "this" within a clicklistener, "this" points to that listener, so it's wrong, you can call getApplicationContext(). And why do you need to extend MainActivity and to implement getIntent()?, i think you don't need that. You are not even passing any extra to the new activity. This should work as it is

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

v.getId() will get you the id of the view, that is the id registered in the R class. As your array only contains strings, the only way to bind the string with the view Id is to manually check it. Build the listener and log your id to identify it

```
mDrawerList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
       Log.d("your App","id clicked "+v.getId());
       //this view is the item clicked by the user
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DestinyActivity.class)
       i.putExtra("optionSelected",v.getId());
       startActivity(i);
   }
});
```

you will get an id like 234252341, and for every item of your list a different id which you can associate with the string

**ORIGINAL**

You have to add a click listener to your ListView and put an action on it depending on the view clicked. Something like this

```
mDrawerList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
       //this view is the item clicked by the user
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DestinyActivity.class)
       i.putExtra("optionSelected",v.getId())
       startActivity(i)
   }
})
```

In DestinyActivity you have to get extras with Intent.getExtras and do whatever you need.
PD: Code is handwritten, check it with your IDE

Comment: Thank you for your help. This might sound stupid, but at `i.putExtra("optionSelected",v.getId());` I didn't give the strings an id. Or do I need to call `navList`?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Do I put it after setting the adapter or create a new function?

Comment: Thank you. I got an ID, but it was the same for every single item on the list, namely 16908308. I also adjusted your code a bit, since it complained about onClick. Any idea what could have gone wrong? I pasted the code just underneath set adapter.

Comment: `mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("your App","id clicked "+view.getId());
                //this view is the item clicked by the user
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("optionSelected",view.getId());
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
    }`

Comment: I have combined the answer from you and other answers, but somehow it still returns my `MainActivity`. Any idea why? I have also updated the code to show what I am using now.